# Python to JavaScript unix time conversion

Tags: javascript, python, datetime

In JavaScript:

```js
new Date(2014, 5, 1).getTime()
// results: 1401561000000
```

While in python:

```py
import time
import datetime
time.mktime(datetime.datetime(2014, 5 , 1).timetuple())
# results -> 1398882600.0
```

How can I convert python time to a JavaScript unix time stamp?

Answer (score 3):

Let’s compare the two results:

1. JavaScript: `1401561000` – 31.05.2014 18:30:00 UTC (note that `getTime()` gives you number of milliseconds, so you need to divide by 1000)
2. Python: `1398882600` – 30.04.2014 18:30:00 UTC

So there are actually two issues:

First of all, in JavaScript, the month index is starting at `0` (0 = January) while in Python it starts as `1` (1 = January). So that’s where the one-month offset comes from.

The second issue is due to timezones. Your local time seems to be *UTC-05:30*, which is where that offset comes from. When you create a date in either language, you are always using local time, so your timezone offset gets taken into account. If you want to enter UTC dates, you can also do this. In JavaScript, it’s simple thanks to [`Date.UTC`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC):

```js
Date.UTC(2014, 5, 1) / 1000 // 1401580800
Date.UTC(2014, 4, 1) / 1000 // 1398902400
```

In Python however, it is a bit more complicated as `datetime` objects are by default timezone-unaware but `time.mktime` assumes local time for the passed tuple. To solve this, you can either make the `datetime` object aware by specifying the timezone explicitely, or by performing the calculation yourself:

```py
>>> datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()
1401580800.0
>>> datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()
1398902400.0

>>> (datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1) - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)) / datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
1401580800.0
>>> (datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 1) - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)) / datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
1398902400.0
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript's Epoch Time starts it's month index at 0.  Thus you are inputting the wrong month if you wish to get April in your JavaScript.

To fix your JavaScript to make it the same as your Python:

```
var time = new Date(2014, 4, 1).getTime()/1000;
// time = 1398916800
```